# How do I use i(t) = c^(dv(t)/dt) and c=q/v and

Tags: capacitor, dc

In this series circuit:
[image: Three capacitors in parallel]

To determine the voltage dropped across each capacitor

The charge stored in a 2 Farad capacitor

The number of charges stored on the capacitor plates

And Determine what value of a new capacitor C that would store the equivalent charge of all the other capacitors

Comment: Are you sure those capacitors are in series?

Comment: Have you tried rearranging the terms in your second equation?

Comment: Consider: 1 farad = 1 coulomb per volt, by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those capacitors are in parallel, not series. Whenever you have capacitors in parallel, the total effective capacitance is just the arithmetic sum.

1. The charge on the 2F capacitor can be calculated using the equation Q=CV. Where C=2F and V=9V because voltages across parallel branches are equal. Thus $$Q_{2F}=18C$$
2. The total charge can be found using the same equation. Where C=10F which is the total effective capacitance and V=9V. Thus $$Q_{total}=90C$$
3. Again, total effective capacitance for parallel capacitors is just arithmetic sum. Thus $$C_{total}=10F$$

Comment: This looks like a homework question.